# How can I do additions of multiple values in Django template?

Tags: django, django-templates

1

```
                  <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-7 text-start fs2 border-bottom border-dark"><b>RT CASH AMOUNT</b></div>
                        <div class="col-3 text-center fs2 border-start border-bottom border-dark"><b>KCC</b></div>
                        <div class="col-2 text-center fs2 border-start border-bottom border-dark" id="cash_amt">
                            <b>
                                {% if total1.realization__amount_received__sum == None %}
                                    0
                                {% else %}
                                    {{total1.realization__amount_received__sum|floatformat}}
                                {% endif %}
                            </b>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

2

```
                    <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-7 text-start fs2 border-bottom border-dark"><b>RT CASH AMOUNT</b></div>
                            <div class="col-3 text-center fs2 border-start border-bottom border-dark"><b>KCC</b></div>
                            <div class="col-2 text-center fs2 border-start border-bottom border-dark" id="cash_amt">
                                <b>
                                    {% if total2.realization__amount_received__sum == None %}
                                        0
                                    {% else %}
                                        {{total2.realization__amount_received__sum|floatformat}}
                                    {% endif %}
                                </b>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

3

```
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-7 text-start fs2 border-bottom border-dark"><b>RT CASH AMOUNT</b></div>
                            <div class="col-3 text-center fs2 border-start border-bottom border-dark"><b>KCC</b></div>
                            <div class="col-2 text-center fs2 border-start border-bottom border-dark" id="cash_amt">
                                <b>
                                    {% if total3.realization__amount_received__sum == None %}
                                        0
                                    {% else %}
                                        {{total3.realization__amount_received__sum|floatformat}}
                                    {% endif %}
                                </b>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

4

```
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-7 text-start fs2 border-bottom border-dark"><b>RT CASH AMOUNT</b></div>
                            <div class="col-3 text-center fs2 border-start border-bottom border-dark"><b>KCC</b></div>
                            <div class="col-2 text-center fs2 border-start border-bottom border-dark" id="cash_amt">
                                <b>
                                    {% if total4.realization__amount_received__sum == None %}
                                        0
                                    {% else %}
                                        {{total4.realization__amount_received__sum|floatformat}}
                                    {% endif %}
                                </b>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

And where I want the result:

```
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-7 text-start fs2 border-bottom border-dark"></div>
                        <div class="col-3 text-center fs2 border-start border-bottom border-dark"><b>TOTAL (A)</b></div>
                        <div class="col-2 text-center fs2 border-start border-bottom border-dark" id="total1">1+2+3+4</div>
                    </div>
```

As the values come from the aggregated querysets, some may have None values too. But my big concern is how to add them all to get their total. I can add two values using `mathfilters` module, but can't figure out how to do with more values and some of them even having None values is also confusing me. Please someone help me get through this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You approach the problem in the wrong manner. That logic should be in the _view_. Just add the values you have in the view and pass it to the template in the context. Also about those `None` values, see [Coalesce](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/database-functions/#coalesce)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I am aware of that solution, sir. I just want to learn `mathfilters` better. Is there a way to do it within the template using that module?

Comment: Yes there are ways to do it (write your own template tags). But is there a _need_ to do it? No, because it is better to do that in the view (Separation of design and business logic).

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Okay, got your point. Thanks.